# How to add a record into table, that is related to another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, relationship

Good day!

I have two tables.

**TABLE 1**:

```
GENERIC [GE_ID / number] [GE_DATEIN / date] [GE_PERSON / number] + ...
```

**TABLE 2**:

```
WORKFORCE [WF_ID / number] [WF_NAME / text] [WF_SHIFT / number] + ...
```

Column `[GE_PERSON]` from table #1 is related to the column `[WF_ID]` from table #2 as many-to-one relationship. I have a simple form to add a data to the table #1 with several drop down boxes. One of these drop down boxes contains a list of names taken from table #2 (column `[WF_NAME]`) by SQL statement.

So when I am ready to add a record to table #1, I know the person name chosen from drop down box, but column `[GE_PERSON]` is numeric and I have to add a number equal to the column `[WF_ID]` which is pointing on name in table #2 (column `[WF_NAME]`).

**QUESTION**: how should I build the SQL statement (`INSERT INTO`) to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Tables in databases maintain primary (usually autonumber) and foreign keys. You need to add `GE_ID` as column in Workforce that referentially links to `GE_ID` in *Generic*.

Comment: I have already column GE_ID pointing on foreign key column WF_ID. Should this two columns have the same names? Or it does enough like I have?

Comment: I am sorry. I was wrong in my last comment - field GE_PERSON is pointing on WF_ID field (both are numbers).

Comment: WF_ID column is unique. It increases every time when I have a new record. But I have repeating numbers in column GE_PERSON in table GENERIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access' combobox control allows the bound column to be hidden from the user while showing identifiable data columns that correspond to hidden field. See this section of [MS tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-of-choices-by-using-a-list-box-or-combo-box-70abf4a9-0439-4885-9099-b9fa83517603#__toc356995229). Once you do so, you will have a relevant number for your querying needs.

Brief steps to hide and set primary key as bound column:

1. For the `[WF Names]` combobox, include `[WF_ID]` in the *Row Source* query under Data tab of Property Sheet as first column:

   ```
   SELECT [WF_ID], [WF_NAME] 
   FROM [WORKFORCE]
   ```
2. Under Data tab make `[WF_ID]` the bound column by placing `1`.
3. Under Format tab, set *Column Count* to 2 (or more for each field in query) but give *Column Width* to first column nothing, something like: `0; 2`

Now the combobox's value is the corresponding `[WF_ID]` of the selected `[WF_NAME]` in drop down list, so any query pointing to the control will be a valid number:

```
INSERT INTO [GENERIC] ([GE_PERSON])
VALUES (Forms!formname!WFNamesComboBox)

SELECT * FROM [WORKFORCE]
WHERE [WF_ID] = Forms!formname!WFNamesComboBox
```

Comment: I don't know how to express how thankful I am for your help! All project was done till I was wondering how to solve this little issue! Thank you - you save me a lot of time and nerves)

Comment: Great! I'm glad to help. Access can be a little dense in all its features.